# Why can't i resize UIimageview?

Tags: objective-c

I tried using the following to to resize a image view:

```
   yellow.frame = CGRectMake(yellow.frame.origin.x, yellow.frame.origin.y, yellow.frame.size.width+4, yellow.frame.size.height+4);
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Maybe it is working. Resizing an image view does not necessarily resize the _image_ so you might not see anything change.

Comment: Thats what i thought too. Could you tell me how i resize the image?

Comment: First thing to try: give the image view a backgroundColor so you can see whether it is resizing or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why it may not work. Check your constraints, check your auto resizing masks, check your `contentMode`, etc.

As matt said, also give a backgroundColor to make sure that it's resizing.